# JPA Criteria API: how to retrieve date in "mm/dd/yyyy" format

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, criteria-api

I want to retrieve one of my column date in "mm/dd/yyyy" format. This column is currently returning date and time both but i want only date in  "mm/dd/yyy" format.

Below is my postgresql query that i want to convert to criteria api

```
select    DISTINCT c.name as Facility,
          to_char(begin_exam,'mm/dd/yyyy') as begin_exam
from  a inner join  b on a.rad_exam_id = b.id 
                      inner join  c on c.id = b.site_id
group by c.name,to_char(begin_exam,'mm/dd/yyyy')
order by c.name,to_char(begin_exam,'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

I searched on the internet a lot but did't find any solution that will help me.  please help me in writing criteria api query for this.

Comment: You could extract it as a normal `java.util.Date`, then format it in your HTML/XML/JSON output or whatever you're using.

Comment: i want to use mm/dd/yyyy format in group by clause.

Answer (score 3):

Criteria API defines `function expression` to execute native SQL functions in the `CriteriaBuilder` interface as follows:

```
<T> Expression<T> function(String name, Class<T> type, Expression<?>... args);
```

where `name` is the name of the SQL function, `type` is the expected return type and `args` is a variable list of arguments (if any).

Here is an example how to use it in a Criteria query:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery(String.class);
Root<RadExamTimes> root = cq.from(RadExamTimes.class);
cq.select( cb.function("to_char", String.class, root.get("begin_exam"), cb.literal("MM/DD/YYYY")));

TypedQuery<String> query = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
List<String> result = query.getResultList();
```

where

- `RadExamTimes`: a hypothetical root entity
- `MM/DD/YYYY`: a database-specific format (in this example 
  Postgresql date format; for Oracle use Ora format, etc)
- `to_char`: Postgresql function to convert date value to string
- `begin_exam`: the date field to be formatted

The format string cannot be passed as is so that the `literal()` method is used to wrap it.

Note: The above example is tested on MySQL database with MySQL function and corresponding date format; but the example changed to match Postgresql syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but i am in jruby (java + ruby) technology . it is giving me error as  NameError: no method 'function' for arguments (org.jruby.RubyString,org.jruby.Ru
byClass,org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.expression.LiteralExpression) on Java::OrgHib
ernateEjbCriteria::CriteriaBuilderImpl

Comment: Thx for the feedback. Shouldn't you tag your question accordingly? JRuby is not mentioned.

Comment: I just tested on my system to verify that it really works and modified the answer as it might help other users with similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT '2001-02-16 20:38:40'::date;

date
----------------
2001-02-16
(1 row)
```

Or you can use `@TemporalType` on JPA entity field.

Comment: i want the date in mm/dd/yyyy format and where to put @temporatType keyword in criteria api query

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the column date in "**mm/dd/yyyy**" format for the sake of displaying it in the front end. Following might work on this case.

```
public class SomeDTO {

@JsonFormat(pattern="mm/dd/yyyy")
private Date someDate;

}
```