# How to format Number to Currency with Criteria (JPA 2.0 EclipseLink)

Tags: jpa, criteria

Is there a way to format this:

```
CriteriaQuery<Country> q = cb.createQuery(Country.class);
  Root<Country> c = q.from(Country.class);
  q.select(c.get("currency")).distinct(true);
```

So when all the NUMERIC currency elements are returned they look like:

12345 -> $12,345.00

123,45 -> $123.45

This way I don't hace to loop the resultset formating strings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379221/java-currency-number-format#2379425

Comment: Where should I place the NumberFormatter?

Comment: I know how to format Java Numbers, but I don't know how to do this with Criteria.

Comment: the point is, why do it with Criteria when it is utterly trivial in user code

Comment: I didn't know it was a complicated thing to do with Criteria. It could have been as trivial as the user code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40008789/2545722

Just needed to use the CriteriaBuilder's function method, which allows developers to call SQL functions. I don't like it because this code should change if the DB is changed.